# Ember: hooking up nested route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get a simple model hooked up to a route nested in a resource. I'm confused because the ember inspector says it is looking for DesktopMessageRoute and DesktopMessageController... but the message template only responds to MessageController (controllers/message_controller.js) and I have tried every combination of filename and location both with desktop appended to message and not. What am I missing?

router.js

```
EmberApp.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('desktop', function(){
    this.route('message');
  });
});
```

desktop_route.js

```
var room = {
  roomName: "room",
  users: ["me","you"]
}

EmberApp.DesktopRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return room;
  },

  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render();
    this.render('message', {
      into: 'desktop',
      outlet: 'message'
    })
  }
});
```

routes/message_route.js

```
var messages = [{text: "hey"},{text: "yo"}]

EmberApp.MessageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return messages;
  }
});
```

templates/desktop.hbs

```
{{outlet message }}
```

templates/message.hbs

```
   {{#each}}
      {{ text }}
   {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `DesktopMessageRoute` like:

```
EmberApp.DesktopMessageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return messages;
  }
});
```

You can remove `renderTemplate` method from `DesktopRoute` and just leave `{{outlet}}` in  `desktop.hbs`.

And this should be your `desktop/messge.hbs` :

```
 {{#each message in model}}
  <li>{{ message.text }}</li>
 {{/each}}
```

See this [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nopikozaca/edit) to see how it works.

Comment: I am actually using multiple outlets in the Desktop template so I think it is necessary? I just left them out to save space.

Comment: Ember renders the correct template based on the path, if the path is host.com/messages, it renders the messages template, uses messages route, controller and model. Unless this is what you want, you can use renderTemplate to render a template in a different path.